# MLE estimator - dividing the log likelihood by n gives different result

Tags: maximum-likelihood

The log likelihood is as follows:

$nln\beta + (-\beta-1)\sum ln(x_i)$

Dividing the log likelihood by n gives,

$ln\beta + \frac{(-\beta-1)}{n}\sum ln(x_i)$

Using these two log likelihoods, I got the same MLE estimator, which is $\frac{n}{\sum ln (x_i)}$. However, I was confused by the different asymptotic properties. For the first log-likelihood, the information matrix is $\beta^2/n$, for the second, it is simply $\beta^2$.

I understand that simply because of algebra, the results will be different. But I want to understand the statistical property: why do these two MLEs for two log-likelihood have different asymptotic variance? How is the difference related to the fact that the log-likelihood was divided by $n$?

Comment: ... because you divided by $n$, of course.  The first log likelihood corresponds to a log likelihood associated with a sample of size $n$, the second to a log likelihood associated with a sample of size 1 where the single observed $x$ equals the term you write as ${1 \over n}\sum \log(x_i)$.

Comment: In the first case, the asymptotic variance of the MLE is $\frac{\beta^2}{n^2}$ and in the second case $\frac{\beta^2}{n}$. Is this difference inconsequential because we're talking about asymptotics?

Comment: The second case is not the real log likelihood, because you've divided by $n$.  Dividing by $n$ makes it a different function of $n$, so naturally derivatives etc. are also different functions of $n$, and limits as $n \to \infty$ will be different too.  The first case is the real log likelihood.

Comment: @jbowman I understand that simply because of algebra, the results will be different. I want to clarify about how to make sense of the statistical property: we have the same MLE estimator, but with different asymptotic variance--why?

Comment: In one case you have a term $n \log \beta$, with 2nd derivative $-n/\beta^2$, in the other you have just $\log \beta$, with 2nd derivative $-1/\beta^2$.  The reason you have a $-1$ instead of a $-n$ is that you divided by $n$.  When you take the first derivative of the other term, you get $-\sum\dots$, so there's still a term there to divide by $n$.  When you take the second derivative of the other term, it's zero.  I'll also point out that it's not the same MLE estimator; dividing the likelihood for a sample size of $n$ by $n$ makes it NOT the likelihood for a sample size of $n$ any more.

Comment: So the key point is that the two MLEs are actually not the same. One is for a sample size n, another is for a sample size 1. Could you explain the reasoning behind why the MLE of n-obs sample is $\beta^2/n^2$, while the MLE of 1-ob sample is $\beta^2/n$? Again, I understand the algebra that arrives at the result. I hope to clarify the statistical reasoning behind it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Under the standard regularity conditions, the Fisher information can be expressed as the negative of the expected value of the second derivative of *the log-likelihood*, and NOT of some *transformation* of the log likelihood.

Your log-likelihood is $L=n\ln\beta + (-\beta-1)\sum \ln(x_i)$, and that doesn't change. For whatever reasons you used the monotonic transfomartion $\tilde L=\frac 1n L$, in calculating the MLE. Since it is a monotonic transformation, naturally the MLE is the same. Now calculate the Fisher information. It is, irrespective of whether you used $L$ or $\tilde L$ in the maximization procedure,

$$I(\theta) = -E\left[\frac {\partial^2}{\partial \beta^2} L\right]=E\left[\frac n{\beta^2}\right]$$

You cannot substitute $\tilde L$ for $L$ in the calculation of the Fisher information as if $\tilde L$ was equal to $L$ - it is not (the fact that $\tilde L$, being a monotonic transformation of $L$ leads to the same MLE does not make it *equal* to $L$).

Another way to look at it is to remember that the likelihood w.r.t $\beta$ function is (and should be) also a joint density w.r.t to the $x_i$'s function. In our case (assuming an i.i.d sample) it is

$$f(X;\beta) = \prod_{i=1}^n\beta x_i^{-\beta-1}, \qquad f(x_i;\beta) = \frac {\beta} {x_i^{\beta+1}}$$
which is a Pareto distribution with minimum value $1$.

Now, could the transformed log-likelihood lead to a joint density?
It would give

$$\left(\prod_{i=1}^n\beta x_i^{-\beta-1}\right)^{1/n}$$

This is the geometric mean of the product of the $n$ marginal densities. Can it represent the joint density of a collection of i.i.d random variables?

Comment: (Yes - the MLE is without the minus). So I understand that $\tilde L$ and $L$ are different, and the MLE derived from them are different. Is the information matrix in the $\tilde L$ case $\beta^2$ then? Could you then explain the intuition behind why these two MLEs have different asymptotic variance? (I added this question to my original post).

Comment: I don't yet see "two" Maximum Likelihood Estimators. I see one, that comes from a sample of i.i.d Paretos, and I see another function, the $\tilde L$, which will become a "log-likelihood" only if it can be shown to represent the logarithm of a joint density function. If it doesn't, then its maximizer is not a "maximum likelihood estimator", it is just the maximizer of some function.

Comment: Hmm okay -- that contradicts what I am taught in class, so I need to sort this out with my professor. I'll come back and edit this question. Thanks for your help!